# Local Storage wont clear in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, local-storage

I am saving my login token to local storage and in IE when I go to logout it hits the landing page but immediately logs me back in again.
Is there anyway of clearing this out of IE?
Currently using this line of code on logout function:

window.localStorage.clear();

Answer (score 0):

You can try to post your sample code to reproduce the issue with IE.

We will try to make a test with IE and try to check the result.

**LocalStorage.clear()** will clear all the data in localStorage. Which may not be suitable for your customers. You can try to use **storage.removeItem(keyName);** to remove any specific data from local storage.

Reference:

[Storage.removeItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)